# How to fix 404 error when users haven't photo?

Tags: php, laravel, rest, microsoft-graph-api

I use laravel and microsoft-graph api.

I need to get my users's photo but some haven't one and for them the api return a 404 error who bloc my page. what I wan't is to put a default profile photo for users who haven't one but i don't know how to pass the 404 error.

there is what my code do :

```
$photoLink = '/users\/' . $value['email'] . '/photos/240x240';
$photo = $graph->createRequest('GET', $photoLink . '/$value')->execute();
$photo = $photo->getRawBody();
$meta = $graph->createRequest("GET", $photoLink)->execute();
$meta = $meta->getBody();
echo '<img src="data:'.$meta["@odata.mediaContentType"].';base64,'.base64_encode($photo).'" />';
```

the error code :
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException thrown with message "Client error: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/XXX@XXX.com/photos/240x240/$value` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
    "message": "The photo wasn't found.",
    "innerError": {
      (truncated...)
"

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include what you have tried that isn't working for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with this api but it looks like you are trying to achieve [that](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/blob/master/tests/Functional/UserTest.php#L37).

I can see from the microsoft graphql test that they are throwing a `GraphException` when [getting back a 404 error](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/blob/master/tests/Exception/ExceptionTest.php#L9).

The following should solves your issue:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;

try {   
    $photoLink = '/users\/' . $value['email'] . '/photos/240x240';
    $photo = $graph->createRequest('GET', $photoLink . '/$value')->execute();
    $photo = $photo->getRawBody();
    $meta = $graph->createRequest("GET", $photoLink)->execute();
    $meta = $meta->getBody();
    echo '<img src="data:'.$meta["@odata.mediaContentType"].';base64,'.base64_encode($photo).'" />';
} catch (ClientException $e) {
    if ($e->getStatusCode() === '404') {
        echo '<img src="MYDEFAULTIMAGEURL" />';
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Code updated**

Comment: Can you please update your post with the error message?

Comment: Updated my answer, that should do the job (could not test on my side)

Comment: Thanks it work, i get no error when users havent photo, there is just one more probleme is the function getStatusCode() is undefined but it work when I delete the if.

Comment: The getStatusCode() might not be available in your Guzzle version